# Is React Native slow, or is performance affected by using Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an old Angular app that I packaged within an Android Webview.  I've been rewriting it as a React Native app using `create-react-native-app`, and while it's super-easy to compile it that way, the performance can’t compare to the zippy old Angular app.  Even just pressing a custom radio button, causing it to change state and styling, takes a half-second or so compared to near instantaneity with Angular.  Is React Native this slow, or is it Expo?  Before ejecting and finding out myself, thought I'd see if anyone knows.

Comment: Did you try to generate a production version with exp publish?

Comment: you left out the third option -- maybe (most likely) it is your code! can you share an example on https://snack.expo.io?

Comment: A bad implementation using legacy thought can easily mess your performance.

Comment: Possibly a fair point re my code.  Here's a snack: https://snack.expo.io/S1ScE8AOG

The strange thing is that isolated like that, the button press interaction is perfectly speedy.  The problem is that in my app, those buttons are embedded 5 or 6 levels down in the view hierarchy, with props passing down to control the buttons rather than the state controlling them directly as in my snack.  Perhaps that accounts for the performance difference?

Comment: Try to build your app as a [standalone app](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html) and check the performance again.

Comment: So here's the answer.  The performance hit is inherent with using CRNA/Expo development mode, as convenient as it may be.  I built an Expo standalone app and a bare react-native app (Android in both cases), and both performed very well.